# module specifier in es6 import and export

Tags: module, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

I'm confused about what the module specifier in these statements refer to:

```
export {bar} from "foo";

import {bar} from "foo";
```

What does `"foo"` refer to? It can't be a file since it would be something like `"./foo"`. If it's not a file, I assume it's an ID. How is the ID defined?

I'm exporting from a js file, but the import would be part of an inline html script (`type="module"`) in the firefox browser.

The browser version (and browser settings) have been verified to work with es6 modules.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ES6 does not specify what the module specifier refers to.
It is indeed just that: an identifier. Nothing more.

It is left to the environment to resolve these identifiers to an actual module. A loader might interpret them as relative file paths, as global ids, as npm module names, as anything else.

In browsers, [`<script type="module">` took some time to specify](https://blog.whatwg.org/js-modules), but it's here finally. A module specifier of `"foo"` is currently invalid, a browser will ignore that module as it doesn't know what to do with it. It will need something that resolves to an URL to load. Jake Archibald [wrapped it up succinctly](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/):

> "Bare" import specifiers aren't currently supported. Valid module
>   specifiers must match one of the following:
>
> - A full non-relative URL. As in, it doesn't throw an error when put
>     through `new URL(moduleSpecifier)`.
> - Starts with `/`.
> - Starts with `./`.
> - Starts with `../`.
>
> Other specifiers are reserved for future-use, such as importing built-in
>   modules.

Comment: Do you have any hints as to how I can find out what the chrome loader allows for the "value" of a module specifier? It would seem reasonable that a reference to the object containing references to the exported objects might be used as a module specifier.