# Jest/Babel cannot find modules without the path prefix

Tags: javascript, jestjs, es6-modules, babel-jest

I'm trying to follow the [Jest getting started guide](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started.html) but with ES6 Modules and Babel.My root folder has two javascript files `sumfn.js` and `sum.test.js`. My `sum.test.js` file looks like this:

```js
import { sum } from 'sumfn';

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

However it seems like Jest is having trouble resolving `sumfn`, even though it clearly does find the file `sunfn.js`.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'sumfn' from 'sum.test.js'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './sumfn.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].
```

If I change the import line to use `./sumfn`, it works. However, from what I read about ES6 imports, it seems like it should be able to find files in the same directory. Is this not supported in Jest perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one of the main reasons why I was confused is because there are a lot of out-dated ES6 module guides out there. In fact, many of the top results on Google seem to be outdated. I was looking at guides like [this](https://24ways.org/2014/javascript-modules-the-es6-way/), [this](https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f), and [this](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html), and they all said that you can import from a module name, without specifying the path, eg

```js
import { double } from 'mymodule';
```

These are called ["bare" import specifiers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules#specifiers), and the guides said that it will by default search the current directory for a matching module. However, it seems like right now they are [not supported in browsers](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/).

Where it gets extremely confusing is that they *are* supported in BabelJS and Webpack, but it follows a different convention. For example, Webpack searches the [paths specified in `resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/), which by default includes the `node_modules` folder. This is why the [Create-React-App example](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) can use statements like

```js
import React from 'react';
```

It seems like the plan going forward is to let the environment determine how to resolve these "bare" specifiers ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930637/module-specifier-in-es6-import-and-export)). Seems dangerous to let every environment resolve these specifiers differently, which could make it hard to make cross-compatible modules, but I guess that's the current plan for now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `./` to tell JavaScript *The module you're looking for can be found in the following file path, relative to the current file.* So you need to add `./` to say *Look for `sumfn.js` in the current directory*.

Comment: but in [this popular guide](https://24ways.org/2014/javascript-modules-the-es6-way/) it says "It’s also important to note that `from 'mymodule'` will look for a file called mymodule.js in the same directory as the file you are requesting the import from. There is no need to add the .js extension."

Comment: also, if you look at the [react Jest guide](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react) it seems like they import from `react` without specifying a directory

Comment: Yes, but JS is looking for `sumfn` as a module *in the current file*, **not** in the current directory, which is why you need the `./`.

Comment: again, the guide that I linked said it will look in the "same directory", not same file

Comment: I found the answer, it seems like these "bare" specifiers aren't supported yet in browsers, but are supported in WebPack/BabelJS, albeit they follow a different convention, which is why it was so confusing. I posted the full details in a separate answer